# cant get jquery hover to work with .live()

Tags: jquery

the second function isnt working?

```
$('.edit_hover').live('hover',
    function(e){        
        $(this).stop();
        var half_width = ($(this).css('width').slice(0, -2))/2;
        var half_height = ($(this).css('height').slice(0, -2))*0.3;
        console.log(half_width);
        var top = ($(this).position().top) + half_height;
        var left = ($(this).position().left) + half_width;
        $('#edit_hover').css('top', top).css('left', left).fadeIn(300);
        //add overlay
        $(this).css('position', 'relative').append('<div class="edit_overlay" style="position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:100%; width: 100%; background: #999; opacity: 0.5;"></div> ')
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop();
        $(this).find('.edit_overlay').remove();
        $('#edit_hover').fadeOut(300);
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) only takes one handler, so you cannot use `hover` (before 1.4.1). Anyway, it is just a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Use these events to bind to:

```
$('.edit_hover')
.live('mouseenter',function(){})
.live('mouseleave',function(){});
```

Or since jQuery 1.4.1:

```
$('.edit_hover').live('hover', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
    // first function here
  } else {
    // second function here
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! NB: I had to change 'mouseover' to 'mouseenter' for the 2nd part of your script to work.

Comment: @ILoveBrisbane: Right. 'hover' binds 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave', not 'mouseover'. Thanks for pointing that out.... fixed :)

Comment: Still seems to be the case in 1.6.2 as well

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: don't use `hover` use `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
$("...").live("mouseover", function() {
    // ....
}).live("mouseout", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: `mouseover` and `mouseout` don't work the same way as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (the events, `hover` is based on).

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery?  You need to be using jQuery 1.4.1 to use `hover` with live. It wasn't supported in earlier versions.  See the Caveats section of the [`live` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/).  Note, however, that you only have a single callback and need to differentiate the event inside the callback to handle hover/out independently.

```
$('.hoverme').live('hover', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```